# Vertical spacing problem related to the mdframed environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, mdframed

I use the `mdframed` package with option `style=1,` which means that `TikZ` is responsible for drawing frames:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=1]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Text
\begin{mdframed}
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text

\end{document}
```

When I compile this minimal example I observe redundant vertical white space below the framed region. It seems that the baseline is not optimally chosen. Does anybody know how to solve this spacing problem?

---

**Addendum:** The vertical spacing problem outlined above is no longer present with version 0.9a of the `mdframed` package.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the new version?

Comment: @Marco: I've tested the current CTAN version. Vertical spacing is now fine for `style=0` and `style=1`. But I encounter another problem: I get no frame at all when `style=1`.

Comment: I see the problem. I must set value of `outerlinewidth` per default >0. So far you must use `outerlinewidth` to get a frame.

Comment: @Marco: You get the frame as soon as you specify a value for `middlelinecolor`.

Comment: Really? I must check. But I know I have to change the current behaviour. ;-)

Comment: @Marco: The problem is that `\mdf@middlelinecolor` expands to `\mdf@backgroundcolor` if it is not explicitly set. Perhaps, there's some problem with `\md@styledefinition`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control the skip below the frame using `skipbelow=<length>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=1]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text

\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}[skipbelow=-0.5em]
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text

\end{document}
```

[image]