# Vertical spacing problem using mdframed environment

Tags: spacing, mdframed

I want to use `mdframed` to add a frame around a text. But the vertical spacing is not as expected. I found the following help page:
[Vertical spacing problem related to the mdframed environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24358/vertical-spacing-problem-related-to-the-mdframed-environment)

The accepted answer was promising and I tested it myself, but I get a different result than the screenshot there suggests.

Here is the answer example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=1]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text

\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}[skipbelow=-0.5em]
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text

\end{document}
```

My result is: [image: mdframed bug]

I have `mdframed` version 1.9 installed which seems to be the newest version.

Can anybody can confirm this behaviour? Even better would be a fix for the problem.

**EDIT:**
After AboAmmar's answer. I noticed an even stranger but perhaps related behavior of `mdframed`. It allows to define a style and use it for a environment afterwards. The following example will use the `skipabove`, but the `skipbelow` seems to be ignored:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=1]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{skipabove=2pt,skipbelow=-2pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle]
Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: mdframed bug 2]

The result is the same, if the `skipbelow` is defined directly after `\begin{mdframed}`. Only `\mdfsetup{skipabove=2pt,skipbelow=-2pt}` seem to change the space after the box, but I don't want to use the setting globally.

Answer (score 7):

In the current version (see [documentation](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) of Version 1.9b), you can set the top and below skip values as:

```
\mdfsetup{skipabove=<value>,skipbelow=<another value>}
```

So, the above example can be adjusted as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=1]{mdframed}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=2pt,skipbelow=-2pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text

\noindent Text
\begin{mdframed}
  Framed
\end{mdframed}
Text\\
Text
\end{document}
```

You can, of course, choose proper values for `skipabove` or `skipbelow`.

Here is the result now:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help. I knew this options but they also behave very strange. The documentation says default `skipabove` and `skipbelow` is 0pt. I would expect this means than no space is used and I also tried to set them manually to 0pt before, but it doesn't do what it should do.
Your example also used a positive and a negative value, but the result is still not in the center.