# Erratic behavior of mdframed environment right after headings

Tags: luatex, mdframed

First of all, I have seen and read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235099/) it appears to be a different albeit potentially related issue.

I'm using `mdframed` 1.9b from 2013 with LuaLaTeX.

Now the problem I encounter can be reproduced with the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,twoside=false,onecolumn,final,openany,parskip=full,chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{nobreak=true}
\def\a{Here goes some really boring text which we use to fill the paragraph, but which is shorter than the standard lipsum and blindtext paragraph. }

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter title}

\begin{mdframed}
    some text box
\end{mdframed}

\a

\section{section title}

\begin{mdframed}
    some text box
\end{mdframed}

\a

\subsection{subsection title}

\begin{mdframed}
    some text box
\end{mdframed}

\a

\chapter{chapter title}

Now with some text prior to the \texttt{mdframed} environment. To show the effect of that on vertical spacing.

\begin{mdframed}
    some text box
\end{mdframed}

\a

\section{section title}

Now with some text prior to the \texttt{mdframed} environment. To show the effect of that on vertical spacing.

\begin{mdframed}
    some text box
\end{mdframed}

\a

\subsection{subsection title}

Now with some text prior to the \texttt{mdframed} environment. To show the effect of that on vertical spacing.

\begin{mdframed}
    some text box
\end{mdframed}

\a

\end{document}
```

Let me show in screenshots. I have a document in which I use the `mdframed` environment to refer to documentation right after the heading for a section. Now contrast the **vertical position** of the `mdframed` boxes in the following two examples:

[image: mdframed environment right after the heading]

[image: text right after the heading, followed by an mdframed environment]

Now I'm not sure whether this is a matter of taste on my part, since I know LaTeX puts a lot of effort into spacing all over the place. But I find it very odd that in the first example the `mdframed` box is essentially glued right to the heading, followed by the vertical skip that seems to belong to the heading; whereas in the second example the vertical spacing looks more sane.

How can I get `mdframed` to yield something similar to the vertical spacing in the second example, even though the `mdframed` environment comes right after the section heading? Or is there perhaps an alternative that I could use instead of `mdframed`?

Edit: incidentally `\begin{mdframed}[skipabove=\baselineskip]` (even 1em or 1ex instead of `\baselineskip`) also has no effect right below section headings.

Comment: mdframed doesn't start horizontal mode and so your parskip is lost. You could try `startcode=\leavevmode`, but on the whole I would advise to use tcolorbox.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thank you. I noticed, however, that `tcolorbox` introduces "badness" as every single instance introduces `Overfull \hbox (10.0pt too wide) in paragraph`. So I got the feeling `tcolorbox` may not be the appropriate workaround. As for the setup, I only use `\tcbset{sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, boxrule=0.4pt}` (derived from the answer below).

Comment: tcolorbox is much better and much more reliable than mdframed. The overfull box is the \parfillskip. Use `\parskip=full-`. Or check http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187339/overfull-hbox-when-using-tcolorbox-with-parskip-half-koma-option (for boxes after a sectioning command one must set the key `before nobreak` in newer tcolorbox versions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can change to [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). The results for your example look better:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=12pt, twoside=false, onecolumn, final, openany, parskip=full, chapterprefix=false]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\def\a{Here goes some really boring text which we use to fill the paragraph, but which is shorter than the standard lipsum and blindtext paragraph. }

\tcbset{sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, boxrule=1pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter title}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    some text box
\end{tcolorbox}

\a

\section{section title}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    some text box
\end{tcolorbox}

\a

\subsection{subsection title}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    some text box
\end{tcolorbox}

\a

\chapter{chapter title}

Now with some text prior to the \texttt{mdframed} environment. To show the effect of that on vertical spacing.

\begin{tcolorbox}
    some text box
\end{tcolorbox}

\a

\section{section title}

Now with some text prior to the \texttt{mdframed} environment. To show the effect of that on vertical spacing.

\begin{tcolorbox}
    some text box
\end{tcolorbox}

\a

\subsection{subsection title}

Now with some text prior to the \texttt{mdframed} environment. To show the effect of that on vertical spacing.

\begin{tcolorbox}
    some text box
\end{tcolorbox}

\a

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to emulate what `\surroundwithmdframed[]{lstlisting}` does with `tcolorbox`? Also, does `tcolorbox` ensure that it doesn't break the environment? I have been using `mdframed` with `\mdfsetup{nobreak=true}`

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, `tcolorbox` doesn't have this command, but it has an special environment called `tcblisting` to format color boxes for listings. It works with `listings` and `minted`. I think non breakable boxes is tcolorbox default.

Comment: thanks a lot. That helps me right now. I'll still hold out for other answers, since I reckon this might be a defect in the `mdframed` package. I saw its authors participate on this site, so it's possible they'll also weigh in.